# Copying user-uploaded media for local Django development

Tags: django, amazon-s3

When I'm developing my apps locally, I obviously need to use local storage for all my media.

In production, I am using S3 for these files.

Is there any way to sync between these two? Or is the only way for my local site to see the latest images that users have uploaded on to the live site to regularly copy the media from S3 to my local storage?